# JSF form-login-page redirect hits before my filter

Tags: security, java-ee-6, servlet-filters

I'm trying to implement a remember-me function in my java ee 6 application, but I have issues combining it with the build-in security feature. I have the following configuration in my web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my-realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

What I'm trying to create is a filter that automatically logs a person in of their session is expired, if they have a cookie containing some data. This works, but when the filter is called, the redirect to login.jsf has already come into effect, before I have a change to do anything about it. I assumed that filters are called before java ee's own security system since they actually are called on secured pages, but this seems to not be the case. Is there some way to let the user come to the same page that they requested instead of being redirected to login.jsf?

Filter:

```
@WebFilter(
    filterName="authFilter",
    servletNames={
        "Faces Servlet"
    }
)
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    public AuthFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        User user = (User)req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        if(user == null){
            String uuid = CookieUtil.getCookieValue(req, "rememberme");
            if(uuid != null){
                UserBean userBean = EJBUtil.lookup(UserBean.class);
                RememberMe rememberme = userBean.findRememberMe(uuid);
                if(rememberme != null){
                    user = rememberme.getUser();
                    try{
                        req.login(user.getEmail(), user.getPasswordDigest());
                        req.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
                        CookieUtil.addCookie(res, "rememberme", uuid, CookieUtil.AGE_ONE_YEAR);
                    }catch(ServletException e){}
                }
                else{
                    CookieUtil.removeCookie(res, "rememberme");
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container managed authentication is indeed invoked before all filters. This is a security restriction.

You've basically 3 options:

- Use programmatic filtering and login instead so that you have more finer grained control.
- Do the job in `preRenderView` event method of the bean associated with `login.jsf` instead.
- Grab a framework which supports "Remember me" facility on top of container managed security transparently, such as Apache Shiro or Spring Security.

Comment: 1. Feels like that this approach would take alooot of time, while getting worse security and having to reinvent a url matching system etc. just to solve a very small problem. 2. How would this help? The user would still be redirected to login.jsf, and i would have no idea where he came from. 3. I checked out Spring Security, but it looked like it had its own security mechanism completely, which would mean having to basicly redo all of my security code/config. Even if it supported request.login(), would I not need to duplicate most of my restriction settings?

Comment: Shiro does look interesting if it can be implemented easily

Comment: 1. Right, you're basically reinventing some spikes of the wheel. 2. The original URI should be available as one of the request attributes (sorry, don't know key from top of head, peek around in request attribute map). 3. I have never used Spring Security, but gather that it can be used in combination with CMS (from the SS docs: *While we recommend people use Spring Security for authentication and not integrate with existing Container Managed Authentication, it is nevertheless supported - as is integrating with your own proprietary authentication system.*).

Comment: about 2: HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI is pointed at my login page, and HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap is empty so I really don't think the original URL is available.

Comment: The request attributes, not the request parameters. `ExternalContext#getRequestMap()` should provide a mapping of them all.