# How to run a PhaseListener before all Filters?

Tags: java, jsf, servlet-filters, phaselistener

I have a phaseListener and more then one filter. I want to know if there is a way to create priority. I want phaseListener will be first and then all the filters. I am using the url mapping `/*` in `web.xml` for my filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I want phaseListener will be first and then all the filters.*

That's not possible. The phase listeners are to be executed by the JSF faces servlet. However, by specification the filters are invoked *before* any of the servlets. You'd need to revise your approach. Apparently the phase listener *actually* needs to be a filter. This is quite good possible if you are not dependent at all on the faces context. The filter mapping can then just be placed in front of all other filter mappings in `web.xml`.

Comment: Strange. We are using Wildfly 9.0.2 and PhaseListeners are called before our Filters.

Comment: @Olivier: that's likely a misinterpretation (e.g. different request or filter's job is done after chain.doFilter() call)

Comment: You are right, it was a misinterpretation due to the fact that PhaseListeners were called before displaying the login page, while Filters were not called at all. Now I don't know why Filters are not called before displaying the login page.  EDIT: I found why here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793737/jsf-form-login-page-redirect-hits-before-my-filter ;)

Answer (score 0):

When patterns match equally the processing order is determined by the order of the filter mappings in the descriptor (web.xml).

So if you want X to be first then list it first.

Comment: i want my phase listener to be first, after this i does not metter