# authentication mechanism NTLM in wildfly

Tags: jsf, wildfly, windows-authentication, ntlm

as the valve in wildfly is no longer available, i don't found any examples NTLM autehntication with new AuthenticationMecanism in wildfly,

waffle NegociationFilter is not working because we are using JSF and phaselistener "aferphase" to redirect to login page.

As we have a login-config with FORM it redirect to jsf component and so phaselistener before all servlet filter.

it is working if i delete the login config and the securityconstraint on JSF pages but not efficient an not securited at all

we don't want SPNEGO solution (with kerberos) and jbossnegociation is working with valve

anyone have a working solution? i found a guy with a NTLMMechanism with servletextension but no explaination and moreover no CODE !on it and i don't manage to make it work....

thank you very much in advance !

Comment: How is this jsf related? And anyone forcing you to use NTLM nowadays should be fired ;-)

Comment: not really JSF but the livecycle jsf force to use phaselistener before servletfilter and i can't change all the code conception, i know but some clients have their constraint and i like fix issue : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793737/jsf-form-login-page-redirect-hits-before-my-filter) so even if this is not jsf related i have to found a way to achieve this

Comment: i make it work with spnego, the customer have to evolve in kerberos, more secured.... thank you